# Create a left and right spacer in CSS around flash content in the body of a website

Tags: html, css, flash, web

**Option 1**

Below is a general layout of a site im trying to construct. The green regions are the sites header and footer. The blue region is flash content who’s height changes depending on what is displayed. The red region are two spacers im trying to construct that bound the flash content and their sizes change according to the width of the browser however the width of the flash content stays static.

[image]

Where im getting hung up is how do i create these spaces in css. I assume that i would use CSS to solve this problem correctly.

For example, in the CSS file i need to set the background color and height as they as always going to be static, only the width changes.

```
#left spacer {
    background-color: #881E42;
    height: 46px;
    float: left;
}
#right spacer {
    background-color: #881E42;
    height: 46px;
    float: right;
}
```

How can i set the width of right and left spacer to (Browser width - Flash Content width)/2 
Where the width of the flash content is static at 920px.

I'm not sure how to govern the width of the spacers.

Somehow the width of the spacers needs to be set to a size of (Browser width - flash content width)/2
In this example the static width of the flash content is 920px and the browser width is variable. so say the browser width is 1920px than the size of each spacer would be 500px per container. I would also set the minimum width of each spacer to 20px so they show up if the browser width is below a certain threshold.

**Opetion 2**

The other idea that i had was to create 1 container which housed the flashcontent

```
<div id="container">
*Flash content scipt goes here
</div>
```

I dont know how to do this or even if its possible, but it would work

```
#Container{
        psudo code
        Color 1: #881E24
        Color 1 height: 25px
        Color 1 width: 100%
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/W73ed/6/)

Updated code.

Example of code,

```
  <div id="header">
</div>

<div id="one">
</div>
<div id="two">
</div>
<div id="three">
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="footer">
</div>


    CSS
    #header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
}

.clear {clear: both;}

#one {
    width: calc((100% - 250px)/2);
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}

#two {
    width: 33%;
    height: 970px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}


#three {
    width: calc((100% - 250px)/2);
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: I dont think it would work to use % as width because the flash content has a static width of 920 px and it needs to be static otherwise the content will not siplay correctly. Then if pixels were used on the spaces than if thte browser window was too large or too small there will be blank space or overlap. The idea of this is that the spacers and the flash content will blend together without any gaps.

Comment: Ok ill keep at it.give me a bit What are the spacers being used for exactly?

Comment: The flash content is not ours exactly, well we dont control the design on it. In the flash content it has a navigation bar that has a height of 25px and a static background color. The idea is for the spacers to match the flash contents nagivation bar so it better blends with our website. And allthough we can adjust the flash contents size we can extend its navigation bar to the entire with of the browser with these spacers if that makes sense. There has to be someway to set the width to a ratio i.e. width = (browser width - flash content width)/2. Thanks for your help.

Comment: does this get us closer? http://jsfiddle.net/W73ed/2/ By making the spacers then using the background of the body or a wrapper as the sides of the flash? This is kind of difficult cause its hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish. Also it has to worth with your code which is impossible to know without having it.

Comment: It's like that however i want "one" and "three" widths to resize based on the broswer window while the width of "two" remains the same regaurdless of the broswers width. I updated my original post with another option, do you think its possible to do it that way?

Comment: I edited my jsfiddle and the sample code in this answer with the calc method. This should work perfectly. Let me know if you need anymore help.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be make the three DIVs float:left and size them as you want, then between the end of the content you'd use a clear and end with the floating area.
If you do it that way, you'll have:

left_spacer | flash_content | right_spacer

The spacers are really only needed if you want to put content in them (otherwise you could use only margins to put #flash_content wherever you want, and not need to make anything float).

To size your DIVs, you would have to size left_spacer and flash_content with a certain amount of pixels or percentage, and right spacer should fill the rest of the space.

You might want to put the three divs in a container if you're using fixed width, too.

edit: actually, I think you won't need to make the last of the three divs (right_spacer) float:left, since it is the last one on the row.

Comment: Using % for the width wont work in this case because the flash content has to have a static size of 920 px to display correctly, this would cause problems when the window size changes because there will be gaps or overlap with the spacers. The spacers width needs to be related to a ratio of the ((browser width)-(flash container width))/2

Comment: You could try CSS's calc(), like this:
#left_spacer, #right_spacer { width: calc((100% - 94px)/2); }

Comment: I've updated NDiaz's JSFiddle to the calc solution and it seems to work pretty well, take a look yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/W73ed/5/